# Neo4J / py2neo -- create `Relationship` in transaction?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

Outside of a transaction I can do this:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship
graph = Graph()
graph.create(Relationship(node1, "LINKS_TO", node2))
```

Can I do something analogous inside a transaction?:

```
tx = graph.cypher.begin()
tx.append(Relationship(node1, "LINKS_TO", node2))  # This doesn't work
```

Or do I have to manually write it out as a cypher query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, got it.

```
from py2neo import Graph, Relationship
from py2neo.cypher import CreateStatement

graph = Graph()
tx = graph.cypher.begin()

statement = CreateStatement(graph)
statement.create(Relationship(node1, "LINKS_TO", node2))
tx.append(statement)

tx.commit()
```